# Extract data within a range using ALOS DEM in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to extract the LULC falling below 500m in Google Earth Engine. But not sure how we do that code here. Anyone who knows please help on this.

Using ALOS DEM here.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? If you don't know where to start I would suggest you look at the section about masking in the Earth Engine guide. https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_05#masking

Comment: Have tried the below but it is not working                                                                 var alos = alos.select('AVE_DSM').rename('elev').clip(region);                                                           
var elv_mask = alos.lt(500)
var com = composite.updateMask(elv_mask)

Comment: what is not working? You need to give more info